# Change coordinates of RectF after canvas rotate

Tags: android, android-canvas

I used this code to draw text vertically.

```
RectF rectF2 = new RectF();
matrix.mapRect(rectF2, bounds);
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(90, rectF2.right, rectF2.top);
canvas.drawText(text, rectF2.left, rectF2.bottom, mTextPaint);
canvas.restore();
```

This works well, but I want to change the coordinates as well. Because later I tap on the object and do the drag and drop.

Now the problem is, As you see in the following image, the coordinates are drawn as rectangle. So when I tap on that rectangle area can only be able to move around the text on canvas.

So I want to rotate the original coordinates as well when I rotate the canvas. I tried `matrix.setRotate` But I can't able to achieve what I want.

[image]

Comment: The code [here](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/verticaltext-part-1/) works for what you want. It rotates the text 90 degrees and moves the boundaries to match the text. It does not handle marquee scrolling and maybe a few other more advanced aspects of _TextView_. [This project](https://github.com/yoog568/VerticalTextView/blob/master/src/com/yoog/widget/VerticalTextView.java) is another alternative that uses paths.

Comment: I want do the operation with matrix. So I will save the matrix values for later use.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. While a view is responsible for measuring itself, it is the ViewGroup that positions the view according to the ViewGroup's rules. (You don't mention which ViewGroup you are using.) You _might_ be able to change the bounds by overriding layout() in your custom view and applying the matrix value there, determine the new bounds and calling through to the super. Another possibility is to make a custom ViewGroup that is matrix-aware.

Comment: Do you want to draw a rotated rectangle? Or do you want to know when the user click on the text?

Comment: @Android_Developer I want to do both.

Answer (score 1):

In onDraw(), you can transform your canvas using a matrix.
And in onTouch(), you can transform-back the screen coordinates using the matrix inverse.

```
private static class MyView extends View {

    private final Paint texPaint = new Paint(){{
        setTextSize(60);
        setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }};

    private final Paint rectPaint = new Paint(){{
        setStrokeWidth(20);
        setColor(Color.RED);
        setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }};

    private final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    private final RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, 400, 150);

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.postRotate(45);
        matrix.postScale(1.5f, 1.5f, 0, 0);
        matrix.postTranslate(w/2, h/2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.concat(matrix);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, rectPaint);
        //Bottom line of the drawn text is at y, if you want the text to inside the rect
        // increase the y by the text height, textHeight is the textSize
        canvas.drawText("SomeText", 0, texPaint.getTextSize(), texPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), isInsideRegion(x, y) ? "Inside" : "Outside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isInsideRegion(float x, float y) {
        Matrix invertedMatrix = new Matrix();
        if (!matrix.invert(invertedMatrix)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Matrix can't be inverted");
        }
        float[] point = {x, y};
        invertedMatrix.mapPoints(point);
        return rect.contains(point[0], point[1]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I hope this works, by the way, can you explain little bit like why we need to do `matrix.postScale(1.5f, 1.5f, 0, 0);` and what is 1.5f?

Comment: This is just for example, it will make the rectangle bigger by 50%. If you only need rotation, no need to include it.

Comment: Since I didn't test it, I'll add the bounty to this answer b'coz I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want drag objects in this view, you probably need to create ViewGroup and place objects as Views. Because all of your object drawn on canvas you can't tap and drag on them.

You can rotate, translate, and resize views and also intercept touch events on them to perform dragging

Your solution works only like Image with text and, if I understand you correctly, you can't do with them what you want

Comment: No, we can do rotate, translate and resize with matrix.